# Separating digits of a binary number?

Tags: c++

I want to create a half adder using c++, for that I would probably need to separate the binary digits to add them one by one. Do I need to create an array for that? for example, for adding the first "index" of the first number to the first "index" of the second number?
For those of you who don't know what a half adder is, it adds the separate digits of a binary number to another number disregarding the carry.

```
It works like this:

 1101
+0011
=1110
```

This is the code I wrote for adding binary digits, how do I mould it to write 4-bit binary numbers?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int halfadd(int a,int b){
  if (a==0){
    if (b==0){
      return 0;
    }
    else return 1;
  }
  else{
    if (b==0){
      return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
  }
}

int main(){
  int a,b;
  cout <<"Enter the two numbers to be added: ";
  cin>>a; cin>>b;
  cout<<"***Half Sum***"<<endl;
  cout<<a<<"+"<<b<<"="<<halfadd(a,b);  
}
```

Comment: [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) mayy come in handy for that.

Comment: Your input is `int` and you want to add it as binary?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i'm a student and haven't learnt anything about "bitset", it's an assignment so i won't be allowed to use that.

Comment: are you sure you understand your assignment right? Cause since you, let's say, write number 1101 on standard input, it is loaded into integer (as number 1101) and not as 13 in binary. Therefore it doesn't really make sense to me. Do parameters of halfadd have to be integers?

Comment: @MarekChocholáček They don't have to be integers, i couldn't think of another way

Comment: then I suggest you take a, b as string and you write yourself a function that converts binary to decimal, then you add and convert back. I cna provide some code if you feel lost

Comment: @MarekChocholáček that way,i wont be able to "half add" them, i have to ignore the carry like in the example i've given.

Comment: @Kiyea Hei let me write some code and we can discuss, I will post as answer

Answer (score 1):

First things first. Let me update some parts of your main first:
I think it is better to for your local variables a and b to be std::string (don't forget to include string header) instead of integers:

```
string a,b;
```

then your call for halfadd can look like this:

```
cout << a << "+" << b << "=" << halfadd(stoi(a, nullptr, 2), stoi(b, nullptr, 2));
```

Note: [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function converts data from string to integer, std::stoi's third parameter is base of expected integer value respresented by string (if you ever wondered).

Let's move on to the halfadd function. Since you have converted strings to actual integer value you can use for example bitwise operators. [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation is exactly what you need. Result of XOR is 1 only when corresponding bits have different value. Let's look at our simplistic halfadd function:

```
string halfadd(int a, int b) {
    // C++ introduced keywords for operators
    // so you can use keyword 'xor' too
    return dec2bin(a ^ b); // ^ is XOR operator
}
```

Last but not least I wrote myself a function which converts result back  into string. It can look for example like this:

```
string dec2bin(int value) {
    string result;
    while (value) {
        if (value %  2)
            result = '1' + result;
        else
            result = '0' + result;
        value /= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```